# Is it safe to store the user information in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, php

Currently I am storing user information in localStorage, but for some reason smth tells me that this must be wrong due security or smth else... What would be the best practice to pass the user information for ex user_id into a http call later.

If I store user_id into localStorage, someone can change it and make calls on behalf of someone's else user_id. Could anyone suggest me the best practice how would I achieve such things that no one can manipulate with user logged in information.

One way I was thinking is, to always call the users/me and get the user info and then make the other call, would this be a better way?

Comment: You could use sessions, then the data is stored on the server, not the client. The client only has an identifier to the record on the server.

Comment: _"If I store user_id into localStorage, someone can change it and make calls on behalf of someone's else user_id."_ `localStorage` is tied to the origin which created the storage object.

Comment: @guest271314 could you explain more what did you mean with ur comment, what I was trying to say that let say a user has a team_id attribute and if I store that on LocalStorage and latter I need to pass this attribute into a http call, this team_id can be changed from localStorage and u will be able to send any team_id u want along with the http call so that should not be allowed user to change his attibutes...

Comment: @HisniFazlija Yes, user could change or clear `localStorage`. Not certain what you are trying to achieve? What is purpose of storing variable for future request?

Comment: @guest271314 i have a table called scores and that has two fields: team_id and score_value. Each user has a team_id , so I need to store the team_id in localStorage when I need to insert records later into that table using HTTP call like scores/teams/36.

Comment: @HisniFazlija How does user get a unique "team_id"?

Comment: @guest271314 every user belongs to a team, so in this case every user must have a team_id when they get registered.

Comment: @HisniFazlija Yes, though how does team receive unique "team_id"? What is purpose of using `localStorage`? To verify that a request to server contains unique "team_id"?

Comment: I was using localStorage to store the team_id, so later I can attach into the http call, when insertion... I guess I could get the team_id from the server side, no need to pass it from the front-end?

Comment: @HisniFazlija _"no need to pass it from the front-end?"_ If process can be achieved without using `localStorage`, is using `localStorage` necessary?

Comment: If your server relies on a user telling it which team they belong to, and just accepts that information unverified and allows manipulation of data this way, you have a completely broken structure. The server needs to authenticate who a user is, and then either verify any information sent, or not accept any input to begin with and only use data it already knows about the user.

Comment: @deceze, Are you saying for example get the user team id from the server side like Auth->user->team_id and not pass from the front-end, if so, what would I do if I want to use the same function for the Admins, they would add records on behalf of the normal users, so how do i pass the team_id if admin is current user logged in, in this case Auth->user->team_id would return null as Admin does not have team_id. thnx

Comment: You figure that out for yourself. The fact is your ***server*** must have the ultimate control over what goes where, *not the client side*. LocalStorage is an irrelevant implementation detail, the important part is that your server accepts an arbitrary value from a client and just blindly trusts it. *There's* your primary fault.

Comment: @deceze very good point, u r right, I should make decisions from the server side, and in this case I dont even need to store the user information into localStorage, except the user access token... thnx for your  help. this makes more sense...

Comment: Can you write in the Answers section so I can mark your answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 2):

Each time a user logs into your application you must authenticate them on the server side and either use a server side session which uses a cookie (or some sort of auth token) for requests back to your server.

It seems like you probably have an insecure web application if a request can be spoofed simply by changing a user id though.

You can store something like a user id or user name in local storage so long as you are only using it for a "remember me" feature to populate a form field for example.